# displaying a description inside a row everytime there is a different result ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a report and it has 3 parameters 2 of them which are 
dates and the third one is a dropdown menu where the user can select 
more than 1 option. Based on what they had chosen the results will get displayed. 
My 3rd parameter gets its values from a really simple query. Allows the user to choose multiple values from DeptID
How can I display inside my report when a result is given results for the different 
options shown in the drop down menu. 
Right now everything is in a whole table. Is there a way to add a header or row and display it inside the table 
every time the tables displays results for a different option. In order to indicate the user with a visual that now they are seen data chosen for their other option.

```
    studentid Last_name First_name  ServiceDate timein  timeout DeptID  Site
   001    lastname  firstname    10/27/2015 5:15pm  8:15pm  5461    School1  
   002    lastname  firstname    10/31/2015 9:20am  3:00pm  5461    School1     
   003    lastname  firstname    10/17/2015 7:00am  10:00am 5461    School1     
   004    lastname  firstname    10/17/2015 1:20pm  3:45pm  5568    School2     
   005    lastname  firstname    10/27/2015 3:00pm  5:00pm  5568    School2
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to show to your users, it seems your requeriment is to show in the table the options selected in your third parameter, for that you can use `=join(Parameters!ThirdParameter.Value,",")`.

Comment: or do you mean that you want to group the results by DeptID? if this is the case , add a row groups and get the grouping (and probably sorting) to DeptID in your dataset. You can also add a header for the group which will make it easier to read. If none of these suggestions help, please post and example of what you want to achieve, at the moment it is no clear.